# Cached data Synchronization to Database

Tags: java, database, caching, synchronization

What are the best ways to keep data synchronized between in memory cache and the database when used in a web application? Specifically, I store large amounts of database data in an in-memory cache using EHcache on my web application. For many interactions, I would like to simply modify the value in cache, and only synchronize it with the database during low-traffic times. What is a good way to do this as well to minimize the loss of data should an unexpected shutdown occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using some kind of ORM like [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) or any other [JPA](http://java.sun.com/javaee/overview/faq/persistence.jsp) implementation?

If not, perhaps you should - because it does exactly what you want in terms of managing 1st / 2nd level cache and data synchronization with database. Hibernate in particular can use a number of cache providers including the very same EHCache; said cache can be disk-backed or distributed.

Comment: I am not currently, but it sounds like I should look into it